# Переход по записям таблицы в C#

Tags: c#, access, база-данных

Доброго времени суток. Имеется следующий код:

```
OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + Application.StartupPath +"/BD.mdb");
OleDbCommand com = new OleDbCommand();
OleDbDataAdapter adap = new OleDbDataAdapter();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
com.Connection = conn;
com.CommandText = "Select * from "+comboBox1.Text;
conn.Open();
adap.SelectCommand = com;
adap.Fill(ds);
dt = ds.Tables[0];
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
conn.Close();
```

Как можно осуществить переход по записям в этом наборе данных? Я вывожу в эксель данные и хочу циклически вывести все записи таблицы. Как это сделать, пробежаться по всем записям набора данных?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//переход по записям  
for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)  
{  
   //данные из поля "columnName"  
   string s = (string)dt.Rows[i]["columnName"];  
}
```

Comment: пишу такой код, выдает ошибку...:


for (int i = 0; i <= dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{

  sheet.Cells[i, 1].Value = (string)dt.Rows[i]["NameTheme"];

}

Comment: Исключение из HRESULT: 0x800A03EC пишет...

Comment: Вы хотели узнать как осуществить переход по записям, я Вам показал :) А в причине ошибки надо разбираться. Она, скорее всего, связана не с выборкой из DataTable, а с вставкой в ячейку Excel.